# Assigning a tolerance to a variable in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two sets of time series data.
I wanted to put them in single plot.
I have used the following code:

```
temp <- data.frame(HMn29_29$avg_val, HMn28_29$avg_val, HMn29_29$h)
ggplot(temp, aes(HMn29_29.h)) + ylim(-2, 13) +
    geom_line(aes(y = HMn28_29.avg_val, colour = "Tempratur")) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = HMn29_29.avg_val, colour = "TempratureA")) +
    opts(title = 'chart_title')
```

And I wanted to assign the +.6 and -.6 tolerance of `HMn29_29$avg_val` in plot.

Sample data of `HMn29_29`:

```
                     h    avg_val
1  2007-09-29 00:00:00 -1.3250000
2  2007-09-29 01:00:00 -0.4670000
3  2007-09-29 02:00:00 -0.4426667
4  2007-09-29 03:00:00 -0.6396667
5  2007-09-29 04:00:00 -0.7843333
6  2007-09-29 05:00:00 -0.5563333
7  2007-09-29 06:00:00 -0.7276667
8  2007-09-29 07:00:00 -0.6260000
9  2007-09-29 08:00:00 -0.7290000
10 2007-09-29 09:00:00  0.4976667
```

Sample data of `HMn28_29`:

```
                     h    avg_val
1  2007-09-29 00:00:00 -1.9225000
2  2007-09-29 01:00:00 -1.6676667
3  2007-09-29 02:00:00 -1.5820000
4  2007-09-29 03:00:00 -1.5716667
5  2007-09-29 04:00:00 -1.8290000
6  2007-09-29 05:00:00 -1.6153333
7  2007-09-29 06:00:00 -1.8093333
8  2007-09-29 07:00:00 -1.9303333
9  2007-09-29 08:00:00 -1.3980000
10 2007-09-29 09:00:00  1.2270000
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I combined your data into one and named "datafromstackoverflow.csv". The modified data is as follows:

```
h   x29_29  x28_29
9/29/2007 0:00  -1.325  -1.9225
9/29/2007 1:00  -0.467  -1.6676667
9/29/2007 2:00  -0.4426667  -1.582
9/29/2007 3:00  -0.6396667  -1.5716667
9/29/2007 4:00  -0.7843333  -1.829
9/29/2007 5:00  -0.5563333  -1.6153333
9/29/2007 6:00  -0.7276667  -1.8093333
9/29/2007 7:00  -0.626  -1.9303333
9/29/2007 8:00  -0.729  -1.398
9/29/2007 9:00  0.4976667   1.227
```

The code I used to plot is as follows:

```
data <- read.csv("datafromstackoverflow.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
p <- ggplot(data,aes(h,x29_29))  
p <- p + geom_point(data=data,aes(x=h,y=x29_29),color="blue")  
p <- p + geom_point(data=data,aes(x=h,y=x28_29),color="red")  
p
```

I hope this will help you.

Jdbaba

Comment: I look for a method that presents the tolerance of HMn29_29 in plot. In other words, in addition to your plot, it should present the area that covered by HMn29_29$avg_val+.06 and HMn29_29$avg_val -.6 .

Answer (score 1):

I have played with the data little bit and come up with this.

I renamed x29_29 to A and x28_29 to B.

I used geom_ribbon function and seems like this is what you are looking for. You can find more details regarding options on geom_ribbon on 
[Geom Ribbon](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_ribbon.html)

The code I used is as follows:

```
data <- read.csv("datafromstackoverflow.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
data
p <- ggplot(data,aes(x=h))
p <- p+ geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=A-0.06,ymax=A+0.06),fill="blue")
p <- p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=B-0.06, ymax=B+0.06),fill="red")
p
```

The graph I obtained is as follows:

[image]

The blue line is for A, and red line is for B. You can add legends if you want.

Jdbaba